# Atribuir valor de uma textarea em uma var e exibir em um parágrafo

Tags: php, textarea

Preciso atribuir o valor de uma `textarea` para uma `var` e a exibir em um `p`, fiz bem simples usando `js/jquery` mas agora preciso fazer em `PHP`.

```js
$('.sendPDF').on('click', toPDF);
function toPDF() {
 var textareaValue = $('.wapf-input').val()     
 $('.geratedPDF').text(textareaValue)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="wapf-input" ></textarea>
<button class="sendPDF">PDF</button>
<p class="geratedPDF"></p>
```

Comment: Muito confuso a sua pergunta ... qual momento fazer isso, porque fazer assim, aonde está chamando o PHP, já fez alguma tentativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará de um form, que ao clicar no botão submeterá seu textarea.

```html
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="texto_a_ser_submetido" class="wapf-input" ></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="sendPDF">PDF</button>
</form>
```

Dessa forma é possível pegar o valor via POST.

Após a submissão, com o  php você pegara o valor na variável $_POST['texto_a_ser_submetido'].

---

Para mostrar dentro da tag p basta dar um echo

```
<p class="geratedPDF"><?php echo $_POST['name_textarea']?></p>
```

Comment: Funcionoooooou, valeu mano